# What am i doing wrong in controller.php code of Joomla 1.5

Tags: php

I have tried validating the captcha by using session id in controller.php

Below is the code i have tried for saving captcha session (by modifying controller.php) - but its not working - what am i doing wrong in this code pl suggest

Its showing server error on submission, i've mentioned the original code (before captcha) and revised code (after captcha)

**Original Code (Before Captcha Session in Controller.php)**

```
 function register_save()
{
    global $mainframe;

    // Check for request forgeries
    JRequest::checkToken() or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );

    // Get required system objects
    $user       = clone(JFactory::getUser());
    $pathway    =& $mainframe->getPathway();
    $config     =& JFactory::getConfig();
    $authorize  =& JFactory::getACL();
    $document   =& JFactory::getDocument();

    // If user registration is not allowed, show 403 not authorized.
    $usersConfig = &JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_users' );
    if ($usersConfig->get('allowUserRegistration') == '0') {
        JError::raiseError( 403, JText::_( 'Access Forbidden' ));
        return;
    }

    // Initialize new usertype setting
    $newUsertype = $usersConfig->get( 'new_usertype' );
    if (!$newUsertype) {
        $newUsertype = 'Registered';
    }

    // Bind the post array to the user object
    if (!$user->bind( JRequest::get('post'), 'usertype' )) {
        JError::raiseError( 500, $user->getError());
    }

    // Set some initial user values
    $user->set('id', 0);
    $user->set('usertype', $newUsertype);
    $user->set('gid', $authorize->get_group_id( '', $newUsertype, 'ARO' ));

    $date =& JFactory::getDate();
    $user->set('registerDate', $date->toMySQL());

    // If user activation is turned on, we need to set the activation information
    $useractivation = $usersConfig->get( 'useractivation' );
    if ($useractivation == '1')
    {
        jimport('joomla.user.helper');
        $user->set('activation', JUtility::getHash( JUserHelper::genRandomPassword()) );
        $user->set('block', '1');
    }

    // If there was an error with registration, set the message and display form
    if ( !$user->save() )
    {
        JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError()));
        $this->register();
        return false;
    }

    // Send registration confirmation mail
    $password = JRequest::getString('password', '', 'post', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);
    $password = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $password); //Disallow control chars in the email
    UserController::_sendMail($user, $password);

    // Everything went fine, set relevant message depending upon user activation state and display message
    if ( $useractivation == 1 ) {
        $message  = JText::_( 'REG_COMPLETE_ACTIVATE' );
    } else {
        $message = JText::_( 'REG_COMPLETE' );
    }

    $this->setRedirect('https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/spurchase?sid=1689498&product_id=2&quantity=1', $message);
}
```

**Final Revised Code (as per Modifications suggested now in controller.php)**

```
   function register_save()
  {
    global $mainframe;

    // Check for request forgeries
    JRequest::checkToken() or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );

    session_start();
        $post = JRequest::get( 'post' );
        if(($_SESSION['security_code'] == $post['security_code']) && (!empty($_SESSION['security_code'])) ) 
        {
        $newUsertype = $usersConfig->get( 'new_usertype' );
        if (!$newUsertype) 
            {
            $newUsertype = 'Registered'; 
            }
        unset($_SESSION['security_code']);
        } 


        if($_SESSION['security_code'] != $post['security_code'] || $post['security_code']=="")
        {
            JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError()));
            $this->register();
            return false;
        }

    // Get required system objects
    $user       = clone(JFactory::getUser());
    $pathway    =& $mainframe->getPathway();
    $config     =& JFactory::getConfig();
    $authorize  =& JFactory::getACL();
    $document   =& JFactory::getDocument();

    // If user registration is not allowed, show 403 not authorized.
    $usersConfig = &JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_users' );
    if ($usersConfig->get('allowUserRegistration') == '0') {
        JError::raiseError( 403, JText::_( 'Access Forbidden' ));
        return;
    }

    // Initialize new usertype setting
    $newUsertype = $usersConfig->get( 'new_usertype' );
    if (!$newUsertype) {
        $newUsertype = 'Registered';
    }

    // Set some initial user values
    $user->set('id', 0);
    $user->set('usertype', $newUsertype);
    $user->set('gid', $authorize->get_group_id( '', $newUsertype, 'ARO' ));

    $date =& JFactory::getDate();
    $user->set('registerDate', $date->toMySQL());

    // If user activation is turned on, we need to set the activation information
    $useractivation = $usersConfig->get( 'useractivation' );
    if ($useractivation == '1')
    {
        jimport('joomla.user.helper');
        $user->set('activation', JUtility::getHash( JUserHelper::genRandomPassword()) );
        $user->set('block', '1');
    }

    // If there was an error with registration, set the message and display form
    if ( !$user->save() )
    {
        JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError()));
        $this->register();
        return false;
    }

    // Send registration confirmation mail
    $password = JRequest::getString('password', '', 'post', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);
    $password = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $password); //Disallow control chars in the email
    UserController::_sendMail($user, $password);

    // Everything went fine, set relevant message depending upon user activation state and display message
    if ( $useractivation == 1 ) {
        $message  = JText::_( 'REG_COMPLETE_ACTIVATE' );
    } else {
        $message = JText::_( 'REG_COMPLETE' );
    }

    $this->setRedirect('https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/spurchase?sid=1689498&product_id=2&quantity=1', $message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line uses `$post` instead of `$_POST`:

```
if($_SESSION['security_code'] != $post['security_code'] || $post['security_code']=="")
```

The code that follows, if the condition is met, raises an error (assuming it's the one you're receiving). Try updating to use `$_POST` and it should fix it:

```
if($_SESSION['security_code'] != $_POST['security_code'] || $_POST['security_code']=="")
```

There are several places in the code-block that raise errors - this is only one of many that could be firing. If you post the specific error, it may be easier to diagnose (if this doesn't actually resolve the issue).

Comment: Hi - Its showing error , have put in the revised code ... Its showing following error    Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=login&Itemid=79. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: Without the session code - form is saving but bi-passing the captcha validation, i think i am doing some error in session code n captcha validation - seek help ... thnx

Comment: @GaganModi Fixing the `$_POST` typo allowed your code to flow beyond the initial session checks, into another error. The only place, in the provided code, that throws a `500`-error is in the `if (!$user->bind( JRequest::get('post'), 'usertype' )) {` block. There doesn't seem to be anything specifically wrong with this code, but perhaps the form submitting the request doesn't contain the `usertype` field? Try checking the form and/or submitted data.

Comment: Hi - Its still showing the same error --  Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=login&Itemid=79. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: Hi - Thanx for replying and taking time to debug this. Its not working, i've put in the original code (as was in original core file) and the last revised code (after changes with captcha session), the modified fied is still showing server error as referred above. Yet not able to find a way